# Learning Stm32f407 timer basics. How to use Timer Count register to set LED?

Tags: stm32f4discovery

I am learning micro-controller timers. My board is stm32f407vg.
This is how I initialized

```
void timerInit(void){
    RCC->APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_TIM4EN;
    TIM4->PSC = 10000;
    TIM4->ARR = 100;
    TIM4->CCR1 |= TIM_CR1_CEN;
}
```

And then in main, i am using Timer4 counter

```
while(1){

        if(TIM4->CNT > 0){
            GPIOD->BSRR |= GPIO_BSRR_BS12;
        }
    }
```

But led never goes On. Led initialization is correct, it works if i put it outside if condition.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer to my question. I was enabling counter in CCR (Compare Capture Register) instead of CR (Control Register).